# OpenThread examples for EFR32MG12 won't work directly as is on their github repository

Tags: openthread

I am trying out OpenThread using a combination of their github repository (https://github.com/openthread/openthread) and the Codelabs (https://openthread.io/guides).

There are examples built for the EFR32MG12 platform - https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/master/examples/platforms/efr32mg12.

I am using the WSTK PCB4001 Rev A03 with the Mighty Gecko 2.4 GHz 19dBm BRD4161A Rev A03. I am able to build the code without errors. I am even able to flash the code onto the chip successfully using JLinkExe. However, I do not see any outputs on the board - no CLI output or response, no LEDs blinking.

I think there might be some error with the HAL or BSP implementations. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you get the issue resolved? I have a few rev A02 of the same board and I do not have any issues on getting these up an running using the provided guide from Silicon Labs.

Comment: Yes, the updated OpenThread repository and silabs gecko_sdk_suite v2.7 solves all the problems I reported earlier.